# Working with implicit array values inside a closure

Tags: swift

I have a books array of struct `Book` that I am looping through trying to find if one of the book's properties is equal to a specific predefined value, and then I'd like to rearrange the element

```
if books.contains(where: { $0.structProperty == value }) {

    books.rearrange(from: $0, to: 1)
}
```

And this is the rearrange function declared in an array extension file

```
extension Array {
    mutating func rearrange(from: Int, to: Int) {
        insert(remove(at: from), at: to)
    }
}
```

With this setup I am getting this compile error:

> Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure

How can I go about achieving it without relying on a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`contains(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2297359-contains) returns a boolean indicating whether a matching
element is present in the array or not, and

```
{
    books.rearrange(from: $0, to: 1)
}
```

is not a closure – it is a code block in the if-statement.

You need [`index(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688966-index) which gives you the position of the first
matching element (or `nil` if none is present):

```
if let idx = books.index(where: { $0.structProperty == value }) {
    books.rearrange(from: idx, to: 1)
}
```

Note also that the first index of an array is zero, so if your
intention is to move the array element to the front then it should
be

```
books.rearrange(from: idx, to: 0)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. The reason I had it to: 1 is because I actually wanted to rearrange it to appear 2nd in a UITableView.